# Change link attribute in head section dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the **href of link** attribute dynamically on button click.

For example : This **dashboard.css** is already active

Now I have to change it **profile.css** on button click.

Problems :

1. How can I achieve this task.
2. profile.css should not be gone after reloading the page.

Comment: you meant from  `<a href="dashboard.css"` to  `<a href="profile.css"`?

Comment: @ Kushal Are you free to use `jQuery` ?

Comment: no i dont want to use jquery..

Answer (score 0):

Use for `<link>` element:

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0];
console.log(link.href);
link.href = "123.css"; // or something else
console.log(link.href);
```

Use for `<a>` element:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
console.log(a.href);
a.href = "http://www.google.com"; // or something else
console.log(a.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="abc">example</a>
<button>click me</button>

$("button").click(function(){
  $("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
});
```

[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mehar/25b7L/)

Comment: @kushal you can replace a with link

Comment: its not hyperlink, i am asking about link attribute which uses for attached external css in html page

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("link").attr("href","your css file name or path of css");
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain what this does, and how it satisfies the requirement that "profile.css should not be gone after reloading the page"?

Answer (score 0):

changing the entire css of page can be done by javascript, after that you can store the settings in cookies.. Here's a [full article](http://alistapart.com/article/alternate) that explains how to implement that.